# Merging {unicode} and {utf-8}

Tags: discussion, tagging

I know that technically [unicode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unicode) and [utf-8](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/utf-8) are two different things, but more often than not the terms are used interchangeably (as UTF-8 is the de-facto standard Unicode file encoding). Should we merge the tags?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There's `utf8x` and `ucs` and `unicode-math` ... but I think it would be ok to let [utf-8](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/utf-8) act as a synonym to [unicode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unicode). This way these closely related subjects could be easier found in order to answer or to look-up.

Not a single [utf-8](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/utf-8) question has been tagged as [unicode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unicode) too, and the other way round. That's a sign for me that they are regarded as either being interchangeably or as unrelated - the latter is not the case. A misleading consequence is that [unicode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unicode) is not even mentioned in the list of related tags to [utf-8](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/utf-8), on the right sidebar, if you filter by [utf-8](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/utf-8)! And the other way round as well - as if they were totally unrelated.

To sum up, I would say: let's merge [utf-8](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/utf-8) and [unicode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unicode), with [unicode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unicode) as main tag because it has a broader meaning.

**Update:** I merged the tags and created an [Unicode tag wiki](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tags/unicode/info).

Comment: I agree, but it might be nice to have some sort of `no-really-utf-8` tag, too.  (For instance, if someone says "I can compile my document if it's encoded in UTF-32, but if it's encoded in UTF-8, I get error *blah*.")  I'm not sure what a good name for it would be, though.

Comment: @Antal I don't think this is a very common use case. One could simply tag those questions with the already existing {encodings} tag. (btw @mods {encoding} should be merged into {encodings})

Comment: @Caramdir: I concur, that's why I'm in favor of the proposal.  It's just something to think about *after* merging the `utf-8` and `unicode` tags.

Comment: @Antal: I think that Caramdir's point is that tags are, by their very nature, lossy.  There's no way of (and no point in) having a tagging system so that there was a _perfect_ tag for every question.  Your proposed question would fit just fine with a unicode tag, I deem.

Comment: @Caramdir: I merged {encoding} into {encodings}. I thought about that encoding might be a verb tag (like compiling), but I think we commonly use an encoding but don't encode by ourselves. So, the noun and thus its plural is fine.

Comment: As I've mentioned elsewhere on meta, I care very little about tags, but merging {utf-8} and {unicode} seems like a sensible idea to me.

Comment: Thank you. Could you please add LuaTeX (and maybe ConTeXt) to the tag wiki (I don't have a {unicode} bronze tag, so I cannot do it myself).

Comment: @Caramdir: ok, done.

Answer (score 0):

Last time I checked UTF-8: meant an encoding that depends on unicode, which **implies** unicode **is** being used or present.

but what about the poor soul who is complaining about his UTF-16 problems and has the unicode tag present

Comment: Erm, what about that poor soul? He'd mark it {unicode} and then hopefully specify if he meant UTF-16BE or UTF-16LE in the question.

Comment: I thought the question meant: should the unicode and utf8 tag be merged? if they want to talk about unicode they should add the unicode tag.

Comment: The {utf-8} tag is now remapped to {unicode}, not the other way around. I think that should alleviate your concerns.