# Should we make [unicode] synonym of [utf8] tag?

Tags: discussion

See title.

[unicode] seems to be more popular at the moment.

If there's any reason against -- there might be questions about utf8 encoding *in particular* but that seems rather unusual and utf8 is default encoding anyway. And we don't have dependent tag for now [Could we make tags imply other tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2781/could-we-make-tags-imply-other-tags?noredirect=1&lq=1)

(I don't have enough score to suggest synonym myself)

Comment: related https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/767/merging-unicode-and-utf-8

Comment: Ah I see, the consensus seems to be in favor; although this new variant (without the hyphen) come up.

Comment: we should just change the few existing `utf8` tagged ones to `utf-8` which since the referenced post is a synonym for `unicode`